# Split column data into two columns & Inserting it to an existing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, split

Split column data into two columns & Inserting it to an existing table in postgresql.

```
Email
-----
xyz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com
```

want to segregate like below:

```
Email1 Email2
-------------
xyz@outlook.com       xyz2@outlook.com
```

```
    insert into s_mas_enrich (email_1, Email_2)
select *,
    split_part(email::TEXT,',', 1) Email_1,
    split_part(email::TEXT,',', 2) Email_2
    from s_mas_enrich
```

Comment: `insert into Table_Name(Email1, Email2)`

Comment: Already tried,  ERROR: column "email1" of relation "Table_Name" does not exist

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. If you want to insert it into 2 columns, first you must have added those columns in your table correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use a union query:

```
insert into Table_Name (Email)
select split_part(email::TEXT,',', 1) from s_mas_enrich
union all
select split_part(email::TEXT,',', 2) from s_mas_enrich;
```

This assumes that your target table `Table_Name` only has one destination email column, but you want to include both CSV emails from the `s_mas_enrich` table.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `string_to_array` to finish the split operation, as below:

```
postgres=# select string_to_array('yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com',',');
          string_to_array          
-----------------------------------
 {yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com}
(1 row)

postgres=# select (string_to_array('yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com',','))[1] as email1;
     email1     
----------------
 yz@outlook.com
(1 row)

postgres=# select (string_to_array('yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com',','))[2] as email2;
      email2      
------------------
 xyz2@outlook.com
(1 row)

postgres=# select (string_to_array('yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com',','))[1] as email1,(string_to_array('yz@outlook.com,xyz2@outlook.com',','))[2] as email2;
     email1     |      email2      
----------------+------------------
 yz@outlook.com | xyz2@outlook.com

postgres=# insert into table_name (email_1, email_2)
select
    (string_to_array(email::varchar,','))[1],
    (string_to_array(email::varchar,','))[2]
from
    s_mas_enrich
```

Notice: the array index of PostgreSQL is start from 1, not zero.